# Function to Launch Another Python Script

Tags: python, tkinter, launch, os.system

I'm creating a program using Python/Tkinter and it involves a main screen with a bunch of buttons. Each button will launch another Python script in the same folder.

I'm trying to create a function that will quit the script and open another. How can this be done?

People have recommended os.system on other similar threads, however everything I've tried has failed to work.

Any ideas/help would be greatly appreciated,

Jarrod

Comment: In what way have your attempts failed? Can you give us an example of what you tried?

Comment: `os.system()` should work. How is your main script calling it?

Comment: Hey @lenz and @martineau, so I've tried importing os, and then creating a function that has `os.system("sudo python scriptname.py")` , but the button doesn't do anything when pressed. Have also tried just `os.system("scriptname.py")`

Comment: Have you tried `os.system("python scriptname.py")` or `os.system("/usr/bin/env python scriptname.py")`? If yes, in what way did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using subprocess library in python.

`import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen(["python", "my_script_1.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output=p.communicate()[0]`

Hope this helps.